# Multi line titles with pandoc

Tags: pandoc, preamble

Given the following `pandoc` preamble:

```
---
title: Data Cleaning and Featurization to Support \\  Data Mining in the SomethingSomething Dataset 
subtitle:  SomeCsClass  Final Project with A and B Datasets
documentclass: extarticle
author: Stephen Boesch
geometry: "fontsize=11pt left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
fontsize: 11pt
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    theme: lumen
    fig_caption: yes        
---
```

Then what can we replace the `\\` with to be recognized/supported by `pandoc` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternatively (to retain the title in PDF properties), use the following format:

```
title: |
       Data Cleaning and Featurization to Support \
       Data Mining in the SomethingSomething Dataset
```

Comment: What are these "PDF properties" and how/when are they accessed?

Comment: I meant PDF metadata (most PDF viewers display metadata by selecting File -> Properties or similar).

Comment: Ah ok - then your answer is better.

Answer (score 3):

Well I actually quickly inferred the answer - but for my own future benefit (or in some offchance for others as well) - here it is:

The `preamble` is in `yaml`: so let us use those capabilities. Multiple lines in `yaml` are specified by leading pipes `|`  - which leads to the following:

```
title: |
       | Data Cleaning and Featurization to Support 
       | Data Mining in the SomethingSomething Dataset
```

Which gives us a nice result in the output PDF.

[image]

OK i was too lazy to obfuscate the title in that screenshot ;)

Comment: @priiduonu just added an answer that preserves the title _metadata_ and thus is better than mine